# Not able to find iSCSI LUN under Win 10 diskmgmr after being successfully being connected via iSCSI initiatior

Tags: windows-10, iscsi

My goal is to assign a Windows 10 drive letter (such as "N:" for example) to a NetGear ReadyNAS iSCSI LUN. *Before anyone asks, the Windows application I am using requires the disk to iSCSI attached. I know and I have attached via NET USE but the Windows 10 application does not allow it.

What I tried: I have successfully used the Windows 10 iSCSI initiator to connect to a new ReadyNAS LUN group:

Within the Windows 10 iSCSI Initiator, the target tab shows:
**iqn.1994-11.com.netgear:secure12:840c091a:recordings CONNECTED**

**THE PROBLEM**
Most instructions I have found indicate that I should use Windows 10 diskmgmr to format the drive (LUN Group), but diskmgmr does not show the drive.

There also appears to be a "Volumes and Devices" tab within the Windows 10 iSCSI Initiator but the Auto Configure button and other options buttons appear to do nothing.

I am obvious doing something wrong. Any help for the iSCSI newbee is greatly appreciated. My respectful apologies if this has been answered before. Pointers appreciated.

Comment: Any pointers appreciated.   Has ANYONE successfully used Netgear's ReadyNAS iSCSI support?   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you see the drive in the Device Manager under Disk Drives section?

Comment: @Stuka, Thank you for the question.  You are right at the key point of the problem.  Although I show "Connected" under the iSCSI initiator, nothing (except for the Windows C:\ drive) under the disk drive section of Disk Manager.

Comment: That's weird. But I was referring to Device Manager, not Disk Manger.

Comment: I should have read your post more carefully.  You DID say DEVICE manager, not DISK manager.  Short answer is NO.  The only disk is the "Samsung SSD 850 EVO...".  What else show up under the device manager is the logical name for the entire NAS drive unit under "Software Devices", and "Microsoft iSCSI Initiator" under "Storage Controller".  I would use a bigger hammer to fix this problem if I thought it might help.  All guidance and suggestions is appreciated.  Thanks in advance. JMW.